# Allow user to insert File/ContentVersion when not Admin

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, crud

*I want to insert ContentVersion as a non-Admin Profile/User.* When I run the code below I get the error below. 
I tried to clone the `System Administrator` profile and call it `nonAdmin`, that did not work. I gave all the related `CRUD` permissions to the user: `ContentVersion`, `Document` and `ContentDocument`, same error.

**Code**

```
system.runAs(nonAdmin){
    insert new ContentVersion(
        title=title, 
        pathOnClient=pathOnClient, 
        versionData=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body));   
}
```

**Error**

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You do not have permission to upload files.: []
```

**EDIT:**
**Solution**

It was a Trigger preventing the insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION implies there is either a **custom validation rule on the object** or **trigger having some validation (using addError on the field)**  and this is not due to platform out of box error or a process stopping insertion of content object. To get it running look into the validation rules and create your test data so that it successfully bypasses the validation rule.

Comment: I have no validation rules on the ContentVersion object. And it works when I run it as an Admin.

Comment: Other thing i can think of is a permission named "Select Files from Salesforce". Do you have this enabled or disabled on the profile ?

Comment: Thanks @mohith-shrivastava, it was a trigger preventing me from inserting.

Comment: updated answer to be more precise with triggers also .